# Como escrever um arquivo .csv em Python incluindo definições do arquivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-excel

Como posso criar um arquivo csv contendo informações da largura das colunas e cabeçalho configurado e coisas do tipo, é possível? ou só podemos escrever os dados sem qualquer configuração?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Um exemplo de uso do delimitador "," seria:

```
import csv
csvfile = "C:\pasta\arquivo.csv"
f=open(csvfile,'wb') # abre o arquivo para escrita apagando o conteúdo 
csv.writer(f, delimiter =' ',quotechar =',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Verifique maiores informações no site: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo para seguir as normas.